# OpenSSL: Verify certificate with CSCA file only works on PEM encoded files

Tags: openssl, certificate

I want to use the verify command on the commandline to verify a certificate using a CSCA file.
This is my call with successful result:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile CSCA_Certificate.pem cert.pem
cert.pem: OK
```

To make this work, I had to convert the files to PEM format. However, I want to use the DER encoded representations.
This call fails:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile CSCA_Certificate.der cert.der
```

The "-CAform" paramater is not recognized by openssl. I get the standard "usage" message.
Does anyone have a hint on this? I'm quite new in openssl.
Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Take a look at the [`openssl verify(1)` man page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Verify(1)).